# How do I list all instantiated objects in Python?

Tags: python

I have a long running processes which may have a resource leak.  How can I obtain a list of all instantiated objects (possibly only of a particular class) in my environment?

Comment: My instant (maybe snide) response, is just to put every instantiated object in a list. Since it's of a particular class, implement methods in that class for handling this list. Additionally, if you make the only reference to these objects those in the list, cleaning them up would be easy.

Comment: Are you using CPython?

Comment: @DylanLawrence, this is for troubleshooting a program.  The code frees up the object instances, and I want to verify that this is happening; i.e. that there's not a bug in that section of the code.  Using gc.get_objects() verifies that there are no dangling object instances causing the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`gc.get_objects()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_objects):

```
>>> import gc
>>> 
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> 
>>> [o for o in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(o, Foo)]
[<__main__.Foo instance at 0x2d2288>]
>>> 
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> 
>>> [o for o in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(o, Foo)]
[<__main__.Foo instance at 0x2d2288>, <__main__.Foo instance at 0x2d22b0>]
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways that you pretty much have to combine. I've used this module in the past to check for exactly that, memory leaks

https://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/

It can make your process use a TON more memory and be pretty slow though, depending on how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

All instantiated objects (I'm assuming just for Python itself in a single module):

`globals().keys()`.

For all of these that are instances only of a particular class:

`filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, some_class), globals().keys())`.

Comment: That is *just one module*, and wouldn't list objects that are attributes of others.

Comment: This only lists globals in the current module, this is **not** what the OP is looking for.